# oauth redirect for permissioning- loop!

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am having problems with the new permissioning in FB- it seems like users now need to go through the oauth client to approve the appli. Code as follows:-

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me" } };


    if (auth.Authorize())
    {
        ShowFacebookContent();
    }
    else
    {

        Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<appli id>&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/<myapp>/Default.aspx");

        FacebookWebAuthorizer auth2 = new FacebookWebAuthorizer(FacebookWebContext.Current);
        auth2.Permissions = new[] { "name, first_name" };
        if (auth2.Authorize())
        {
            Label1.Text = "Authorized";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Not Authorized";
        }

    }
```

The problem is that when a new user logs in- it bounces off to the oauth site, which does its thing, then nicely redirects back to the calling page- then loops & crashes out.
It would appear that it is taking a while for the oath to propagate, so the code behind is re-triggering the oauth redirect- etc...?

The only way I can get this to work is add as above, get a user to log in, they auth then loop & crash, then I comment out the redirect & they are uthorised (ie. auth2.name="Billbo Baggins" or whatever).

Does anyone have any handy hints or a work around for this- I have spent 3 days now going through all the (PHP centric) examples etc to no avail.

Kindest, Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of the Facebook C# SDK. I am the author of the SDK and I can't even remember this code... So my recommendation is that you upgrade to version 6. You may also want to take a look at the ASP.NET Facebook Template which has much more robust authentication helpers. http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update/facebook-application-template-tutorial

Additionally, you can find the library that was written for that template here: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook. The source code is here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

If you can't upgrade, you may want to download the source of the old version of the Facebook C# SDK from github and take a look if you can step through the code to find the problem. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/tree/v5